# Labeled balls and labeled boxes at least X in a box

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am having a problem to solve all the exercises that involve the "at least $1$ ball need to be in box #2" kind of problems.

> For example: there are $8$ numbered cells and we drop $10$ numbered balls into them (each cell can contain unlimited number of balls). What is the probability that cell number $1$ will contain $0$ balls and cell number $2$ will contain at least $1$ ball?

What I did is to calculate the probability of cell number $1$ to be empty $(0.263)$ and the probability of cell number $2$ NOT containing $0$ balls $(1 - 0.263)$ and then I multiplied them both getting a result of $0.19$ which is wrong.

I searched google and found this https://www.uni-due.de/~hn213me/mt/w13/isedm/KOBallsBoxes.pdf case 1.1.2 but the problem is that we didn't learn about Stirling numbers and we never gonna learn about them as far as I know (seems way too advance for this course).

How do I solve these kind of exercises? Thanks in advance

Comment: The numbers on the balls are never used, and no distribution is specified. My answer assumes that each ball is dropped independently, with equal probability for each box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation incorrectly assumes that the two events are independent.

One way to get the right result is to calculate the probability that cell $1$ is empty and subtract the probability that cell $1$ and cell $2$ are empty; what's left is the probability that cell $1$ is empty and cell $2$ isn't:

$$
\left(\frac78\right)^{10}-\left(\frac68\right)^{10}\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks how did you know that the two events are dependent? also if you take the probability that cell 1 is empty and subtract from it the probability that cell 1 + 2 empty why what's left is that only cell 1 is empty(still trying to digest it meanwhile)?

Comment: @TheOne: Cell $1$ being empty makes it less likely that cell $2$ is empty. (If that's not obvious, consider the extreme case where cells $1$ through $7$ are empty; then it's certain that cell $8$ is not empty.) Even if I hadn't seen this, the mere fact that you correctly calculated the probability for independent events and got an incorrect result implied that the events are dependent. On your other question, I suggest drawing a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 4):

Denote with $E_i$ the event that box $i$ is empty for $i=1,2,\dots,10$. Then you want to calculate the probability $P(E_2^c\cap E_1)$ which can be found as \begin{align}P(E_2^c\cap E_1)&=P(E_2^c\mid E_1)P(E_1)\\[0.2cm]&=\left(1-P(E_2\mid E_1)\right)P(E_1)\\[0.2cm]&=\left(1-\frac{6^{10}}{7^{10}}\right)\left(\frac{7^{10}}{8^{10}}\right)=\frac{7^{10}-6^{10}}{8^{10}}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks it helped me to solve a more complicated question

Comment: Yes, indeed. This notation was not necessary for this one, but helps when things get more complicated. You are welcome.